# Select Nested JSON in Oracle stored as String

Tags: sql, json, oracle

How to fetch the code and reason from the below JSON through a oracle sql query. Validation_Errors is a string.

```json
{
    "validation_errors": "[{\"Code\": \"505\", \"Reason\": \"Applicant Potentially Deceased\"}, {\"Code\": \"507\", \"Reason\": \"Applicant Tax ID Discrepancy\"}, {\"Code\": \"508\", \"Reason\": \"Applicant Name Discrepancy\"}]",
}
```

Comment: I tried nested path, but the query isnt returning any results

Comment: You said yourself **validation_errors** (all lower-case, not as you wrote it) is a **string**. It really is - it is enclosed in single-quotes. At that point, the fact that the string itself *looks* like a JSON array is immaterial. There is no "nested path" in your JSON. It seems that you do ***not*** want the value of "validation_errors" to be a string; you want it to be a JSON array (which should NOT be enclosed in double-quotes!) So, please clarify.

Comment: And, actually, it's even worse. The value of `validation_errors` is a string, enclosed in double-quotes. The string itself also contains double-quotes, which are **not escaped**. So, your input string is invalid JSON (not just a valid JSON with a structure different from what you thought it was). You also have an errant comma at the end, right before the closing `}` - I believe that is also a fatal error.

Comment: The inner quotes are escaped; the unformatted code just didn't show that. A minor part of the issue though... It would be helpful if you edited the question to show your query attempt, expected result, and the context - whether this value is a value in a  column, or user input, for example, and the data type. It would also be helpful to know your Oracle version as JSON support is relatively recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you could do (tested on Oracle 12.2.0.1). Note that I first extract the `VALIDATION_ERRORS` string with one application of `JSON_VALUE`; then I treat the resulting string as a JSON on its own (this takes care of those offending double-quotes) to extract what you need.

Note that JSON is case sensitive; you must pay attention to that. On the other hand, it turns out that the extra comma following your "array presented as single string" is silently ignored - it doesn't cause the query to fail.

```
with
  inputs (json_str) as (
    select
'{
    "validation_errors": "[{\"Code\": \"505\", \"Reason\": \"Applicant Potentially Deceased\"}, {\"Code\": \"507\", \"Reason\": \"Applicant Tax ID Discrepancy\"}, {\"Code\": \"508\", \"Reason\": \"Applicant Name Discrepancy\"}]",
}'
    from dual
  )
, prep  (error_codes) as (
    select json_value(to_clob(json_str), '$.validation_errors')
    from   inputs
  )
select code, reason
from   prep, json_table(error_codes, '$[*]'
                              columns code   number        path '$.Code',
                                      reason varchar2(100) path '$.Reason')
;

CODE REASON                        
---- ------------------------------
 505 Applicant Potentially Deceased
 507 Applicant Tax ID Discrepancy  
 508 Applicant Name Discrepancy
```

**EDIT** - Side comment about the need for `to_clob` in the `prep` subquery in my solution.

I used a subquery in the `with` clause to simulate the input string. Oracle views that string literal as `CHAR` data type (in particular, not `VARCHAR2`!) On the other hand, `JSON_VALUE` expects a text literal, or a column (as in our case) of type `VARCHAR2`, `CLOB` or `BLOB`. Rather than creating a stored table with column of type `VARCHAR2` or `CLOB`, I took the shortcut of using `TO_CLOB` in my solution. In real life, that is probably overkill.